# How to keep UITableViewCell textLabel position fixed on swipe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to keep `UITableViewCell` textLabel position fixed on swipe, while using Default `UITableViewCell`.

On swipe `textLabel` text goes left and outside the screen.

Related code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.

        return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

           //code related to delete row

        }

}
```

Check images below for clear understanding:

***Before swipe:***

[image]

***After swipe:***

[image]

Comment: @Ronak This is a default. If u want visible label value after swipe then, change UILabel Position after swipe means set frame `self.lbl.frame=CGRectMake(100,5,50,10)` like this.

Comment: In setEditing method, you could adjust constraint and frame of textlabel

Comment: 'Question can be marked invalid' can you explain why?@Sharpkits

Comment: but it is default cell not a custom one@Flipper

Comment: My Bad.. please ignore.. realised i was wrong

Comment: @RonakChaniyara Also possible in default cell

Comment: can you give basic code for the same@MonikaPatel

Comment: @RonakChaniyara You r using `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` this method?

Comment: No, how can i use that method and what to write to make textLabel position fixed?@MonikaPatel

Comment: Please share your code, which are u used for make swappable cell @RonakChaniyara

Comment: Using just two methods, added code@MonikaPatel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125684/discussion-between-monika-patel-and-ronak-chaniyara).

Comment: Hey @RonakChaniyara have you tried  `cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` into `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Yes, but want same alignment, any another way?@Maddyヅヅ

Comment: Have you Done @RonakChaniyara?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4.0f, 4.0f, size.width, size.height); 
    self.textLabel.frame =  frame;
    self.textLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

override this method...

Answer (score 0):

I think contentView moves when you swipe, so try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame = CGRectOffset(self.textLabel.frame,0-self.contentView.frame.x,0);
    self.textLabel.frame =  frame;
}
```

Comment: How to use `layoutSubviews` for default cell?

Comment: You will have to subclass the cell to change its behaviour

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one:

```
#pragma mark- swipeable cell

    -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.textLabel.frame=CGRectMake(30, 2, 50, 10);

            UITableViewRowAction *unlink_button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
              {

                     [self.accountsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                     cell.textLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0, 2, 50, 10);
                     [self deleteFunction];
              }];
             unlink_button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //arbitrary color

             return @[unlink_button];
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // you need to implement this method too or nothing will work:

    }

    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     return YES;
    }
```